# Need to get the value of a field on a row that I am clicking a button

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a list view at the bottom of a SharePoint page (aspx) and each record is a contact that provides support.  I have Name, Email address, and a button that should open an email and grab the email address that is next to it.  The button is added on the screen via js and is NOT part of the list view.  How does the button clicking function get that address that is just to the left of it?

I have been looking and looking.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    addButtons();
});
function addButtons(){
     var $t = $('#js-listviewthead-WPQ2').next().next().find('tr');
    $t.each(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' id='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail();'>");
    });
}
function openMail(){
    var emailString = "mailto:";
    var emailID = getEmail('SharePointName');
//alert(emailID);

    emailString += emailID ;
    emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
    emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;;
    //alert(emailString);
    location.href=emailString;
}
function getEmail(title) {
    var userEmail = "Steve.@Wi.gov";
    return userEmail;
}
</script>
```

I want to take the email address and append it to the emailString to create the appropriate href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the code below to achieve it, modify the "listTitle" in the code to make it works in one list view web part.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
     addButtons();
});
function addButtons(){
    var listTitle="CustomList";
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='Help' class='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail(this);'>");
    });
}
function openMail(btn){
    var emailString = "mailto:";
    var emailID = $(btn).prev("td").text();
    //alert(emailID);

    emailString += emailID ;
    emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
    emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;;
    //alert(emailString);
    location.href=emailString;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thank you very much.